# Looping over data submittted via jquery ajax routine with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

If FF firebug window, I see this is being passed to my coldfusion action page:

```
RowOrder[]=&RowOrder[]=row_5&RowOrder[]=row_2&RowOrder[]=row_1&RowOrder[]=row_3&RowOrder[]=row_4&RowOrder[]=row_6&RowOrder[]=row_7&RowOrder[]=row_8&RowOrder[]=row_11
```

Now I need to loop over this to get the updated sort order but due to the [], I'm having issues.  How can I loop over this so that I can update my table???  I expected this to be the easy part but I'm obviously missing something.

**+** I'm using the jquery plugin (http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/). **+**

Here is the code I'm using to loop over the submitted data:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "RowOrder")>
<!---<cfset variables.Order = ReReplaceNoCase(form.RowOrder, "(&){0,1}row_\[\]=", ",", "all") />--->    
<cfset variables.Order = ReplaceNoCase(form["RowOrder[]"],"row_","","all")>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ListLen(variables.Order)#" index="index">
<cfquery name="qryOrder" datasource="#dsn#">
update  SystemTypes
set Order = <cfqueryparam value="#index#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
where WETypeNum = <cfqueryparam value="#ListGetAt(variables.Order, index)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
</cfquery>
</cfloop>
</cfif>
```

**+** The ajax code I'm using is as follows:

```
$("#RowOrder").tableDnD({
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
        var RowOrderData = $.tableDnD.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../ajax/UpdateListingOrder.cfm',
            cache: false,
            data:  RowOrderData
        });
    }   
});
```

**+**

The **+** indicates information that was added after posting question

Comment: Could you please post your jQuery code as well?

Comment: @Russ - Leigh has answered the question but I have provided the code as you requested.

Comment: `(&){0,1}` = unnecessarily long-winded way of making an ampersand character optional when all that is needed to be written in order to achieve identical functionality is just these two characters: `&?`

Comment: Actually, based on the currently provided information, that rereplace isn't doing anything at all - because `row_` comes _after_ the `[]=` text, and the ampersand comes _before_ `RowOrder`, so either the replace isn't happening or things aren't as they have been stated.

Comment: I am terrible at regex's, but Peter's right. You would need a different expression if the goal is to extra the numeric portions ie `2,3,...` from the value `row_2,row_3,...`

Comment: I'm not very good with regex either but I was able to figure out what Leigh as doing and just used this:  `<cfset variables.Order = ReplaceNoCase(form["RowOrder[]"],"row_","","all")>` and it is working.

Comment: Ah. A plain string replace, even better.

Comment: There's no need for the RegEx actually as the TableDnD plugin has its own parser. Simply change the underscore to a hyphen in your html table row id values, i.e. row-#number# instead of row_#number#. By default, TableDnD will strip out everything up to and including the hyphen before the form is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the problem manifesting itself? Are you getting an error, the query is not executing, .. ?

Dump the `FORM` scope to verify the name of field being passed? It looks like `FORM['RowOrder[]']` rather than `form.RowOrder`. In which case you would need to use:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "RowOrder[]")>
    <cfset variables.Order = ReReplaceNoCase(form["RowOrder[]"], "(&){0,1}row_\[\]=", ",", "all") />
    ... rest of code ...
<cfelse>
    oops, that variable name does not exist
</cfif>
```

Comment: Do not just downvote - leave a comment and explain what you think is wrong or how to improve the answer. Otherwise it is defeats the point of SO.

Comment: Apologies, It was meant to be an up vote but the the vote got locked - Edit your answer and I'll amend.

Comment: @Leigh thanks.  I see I missed the brackets in the regular expression.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AlexP - Done and no worries, that is happened to me too. I just commented because I think downvotes should be constructive. dlackey - Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not match the number rather than replace?

I've done the regex match within the loop - You can then focus on just one part of the string at a time.

An an illustration of the approch:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "rowOrder")>
  <cfset data = listToArray(form.rowOrder, "&")/>
  <cfif not arrayIsEmpty(data)>
    <cfloop form="1" to="#arrayLen(data)#" index="index">
      <cfset match = reFind("[1-9][0-9]+", data[index], 1, true)/>
      <cfif arraySum(match)>
        <cfset weTypeNumber = val(mid(data[index], match["pos"], match["len"]))/> 
        <cfquery name="qryOrder" datasource="#dsn#">
         UPDATE
            system_types
          SET 
            order = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#index#"/>
          WHERE
            we_type_num = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#weTypeNumber#"/>
        </cfquery>
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Your solution might have worked but I did not attempt it since Leigh's solution was code that I'm more familiar with.  Your solution does look interesting and if I have time, I'll come back and study your solution closer and try it.